# Такие, как вы, не умеете (согласование окончаний)

Tags: окончания

Обращаясь к одному человеку, будет ли правильно сказать: «Такие, как вы, не умеете просить»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно будет:

> *Такие, как вы, не уме**ют** просить.*

То есть либо *"вы не умеете",* либо *"такие не умеют".*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Не за что, JailtriX!